# How can I hide/cancel the default incoming screen

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

I am currently intercepting a call and forwarding it to my customized "oncallscreen" activity. However, before getting to my screen it will flash to the default "oncallscreen". How can I hide/cancel this screen so when receiving call I get only my customized screen.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        Log.w("DEBUG", state);
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            String phoneNumber = extras
                    .getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to intercept broadcast `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` with highest possible priority, then if in your `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` you will cancel broadcast through `BroadcastReceiver.abortBroadcast()` you will be able to stop default incoming call screen to be shown, since default application won't receive incoming call broadcast. After that you're free to show your own Activity.

Comment: Not sure if this used to work, but it does not work in Android 4.1.2 - the PHONE_STATE broadcast is non-ordered, so you get an error when trying to abort the broadcast as you can not abort non-ordered broadcasts.

Comment: What is the highest priority for receiving the incoming call broadcast.